# How do file extensions work?

Tags: windows, file, file-extension, file-type

I did a quick Google search of "how do Windows extensions work," but it only came up with how to change file extensions.

I was making my own file extension for an image compressor, and as of now you'd have to load the text file into a program and its processed, but in a real-world environment that's not something you want to make people use.

I'm not saying I want to build the next best image compressor but it'd be useful to understand how file extensions work.

I understand a file had content, and the content is defined for use by the extension, but when you execute a file (double click) what happens?

If I click a **.x** file (example), would there be a bind that has to be done in a system/environment level, to say point to a batch file that runs everything else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Search for *associating a file extension*.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758090(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you my lovelies, not the best with googling I apologise

Comment: In a Command Prompt it reports on really old ways of association, which happens to be how the majority of associations work. The Documentation is for the **recommended way** not the old ways that still work, and are the majority. `ftype /?` and `assoc /?`.

Comment: [Implementing a Custom File Format > File Types and File Associations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144104(v=vs.85).aspx)